# how do i return the number of occurrences of the letter c

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
public int frequency (char c)
{
    int numOccurrences = 0;
    String ltr = "letters";
    ltr = ltr.toLowerCase();
    for (int i = 0; i < ltr.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (l.charAt(0) == l.charAt(1))
        {
            numOccurrences = numOccurrences + 1;
        }
    }
    return numOccurrences;
}

public class TextAnalyser
{
    private int   letters;     // the total number of letters analysed 

    private int[] frequencies; // the number of occurrences of each letter of the alphabet (case-insensitive)

    // initialise the instance variables 
    public TextAnalyser()
    {
        this.letters = 0;
        this.frequencies = new int[26];
    }

    public TextAnalyser(String initial)
    {
        this.letters = 0;
        this.frequencies = new int [26];
        this.analyse(initial);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format you code.

Comment: i don´t know but i feel like half of your code is missing in the question.

Comment: `if ((c) == l.charAt(i))
        {
            numOccurrences = numOccurrences + 1;
        }`

Comment: Some obvious problems: the frequency() method has a parameter named `c`, but it's never used anywhere in the method. The loop inside the method uses `i` to loop over the indices of the string, but never uses it either.

Comment: Please add a bit more information instead of just copy-pasting your code..

Comment: @ashwinbhy thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If am able to get you right, you want to count the occurrence of character c in a string? if yes then StringUtils has what you can use

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(CharSequence myString, CharSequence subString);
```

this Counts how many times the substring appears in the myString.
read more from [Here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)